# How to get all dictionary keys ('LazyMapCollection<..>' error)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a problem with getting all dictionary keys.
When I call `.keys`, I get error as follows.
And I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks.

error:

```
Value of optional type 'LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String, ChatroomMember>, String>?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

```
class Chatroom:Model {
    var id:String = ""
    var members:[String:ChatroomMember] = [String:ChatroomMember]()

}

class ChatroomMember:Model {
    var id:String = ""
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var chatroom:Chatroom?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var memberUsers:[String] = [String](chatroom?.members.keys) // get Error    

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply unwrap your `chatroom`:

```
var memberUsers:[String] = [String](chatroom!.members.keys)
```

Or (if `chatroom` has a chance to remain uninitialized) use optional `if let` unwrap:

```
var memberUsers:[String]
if let chatroom = chatroom {
    memberUsers = Array(chatroom.members.keys)
} else {
    memberUsers = []
}
```

Or if your entire app depends on presence of `chatroom`, guard it:

```
        guard let chatroom = self.chatroom else {
            // chatroom is not here! 
            return
        }

        var memberUsers = Array(chatroom.members.keys)
```

P.S. You can rely on Swift type inference and use `Array(..)` instead of `[String](..)` to cast lazy `keys` collection to normal array.